# Gtkmm compiling error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, mingw, gtkmm

OS: Windows 7

Compiler: MinGW

IDE: Code::Blocks

I just installed Gtkmm on my computer in the folder C:/gtkmm/ and set up an example program. When I compiled it, it gave the error "gtkmm.h: No such file or directory"

I tried setting the PATH variable to C:/gtkmm/include and C:/gtkmm/gtkmm-2.4, but neither worked. Then I tried using #include "C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm.h" and that just gave a ton of errors saying that it doesn't know where a few dozen files are.

I've also heard that you need to put `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs` in the compiler options, but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pkg-config is a helper function for adding cflags and lib paths to the compiler line.

What you will need to do is add the libraries and cflags path to the compiler line. I am not 100% sure how to do that in code::blocks., though

In ubuntu 11.04, you need all these to compile even a simple gtkmm program:

Libs (pkg-config --libs gtkmm-2.4:

`-pthread -lgtkmm-2.4 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-2.4 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0`

cflags paths (pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-2.4):

`-I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/gtkmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/gtkmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-unix-print-2.0 -I/usr/include/gdkmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/gdkmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0`

Basically you would have to change every instance of `/usr/include/` and `/usr/lib/` to `c:\path-to-library\`

I am not sure how much of the above you need with MinGW, but with GCC on Linux, dropping any of them makes gtkmm programs not compile. Hope that at least puts you on the right path.

Comment: Gosh, that really sucks... Maybe I can make/find a project template that does that for me.

Comment: yes, it is one of the benefits to gtkmm programming on Linux. all of that is wrapped up nicely in a simple command.
I would check out Eclipse, if you can. It has a very easy way to add include directories and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with PATH variable? The global windows search PATH for executables? That would be wrong.

You need to look in your IDE for `Include search path` or `header search path` or something like that.

Does that pkg-config command work for you when you execute it on the command line? Such a pkg-config when used on a unix system is enclosed in backticks ` which causes it to be substituted by it's output. Don't know if your IDE can do that but if it works from the command line you have at least a list of all includes needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use autotools C++ project. You need only edit two files `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`.
Add this line to `configure.ac`

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GTKMM], [gtkmm-3.0])
```

and these lines to `Makefile.am`

```
program_CPPFLAGS = $(GTKMM_CFLAGS)
```

program_LDADD = $(GTKMM_LIBS)